# Updating a status message in a sidebar with Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a pretty simple Google Apps script that runs a series of functions on a Google Sheet.  The actual functions work fine, and displaying the Google App Sheet is not a problem at all.

The issue I am having is that I would like to display some kind of progress to the user after they hit submit and start the function, however, there doesn't seem to be anyway to send messages from the server to the client while the function is **running**, only in a return value.

For example, if I did this:

SERVER CODE:

```
function computePO() {
   for (i=1; 1 < 10000; i++) {
     // do stuff that takes some time
     // want to update user with a log message here
   }

   return "done";
}
```

CLIENT CODE in HTML:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateMessage).computePO(this);        

function updateMessage(data) {
   document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = data;
}
```

Then it will only display the done message in the sidebar when the entire routine is done, which isn't useful.  I want to send status messages the entire time to keep the user informed but can't seem to find a way to do this.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot know about your actual script, in your situation, how about converting the script of Google Apps Script in your for loop to Javascript? But, when this was not suitable for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a status bar using HTML Service and Cache Service.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function startProgress() {
  let progress = 0;
  CacheService.getUserCache().remove("Progress");
  CacheService.getUserCache().put("Progress",JSON.stringify({progress:0}));
}

function runProgram() {
  let progress = 0;
  while( progress < 100 ) {
    progress++;
    Utilities.sleep(10);
    CacheService.getUserCache().put("Progress",JSON.stringify({progress:progress}));
  }
}

function getProgress() {
  let cache = JSON.parse(CacheService.getUserCache().get("Progress"));
  return cache.progress;
}
```

**HTML_StatusBar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="progressBar">Percent Complete:</label>
    <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100"> hi </progress>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="runProgram()">
    <script>
      function getProgress() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function (progress) {
            if( progress === 100 ) {
              document.getElementById("progressBar").value = 100;
              alert("done");
              return;
            }
            document.getElementById("progressBar").value = progress;
            getProgress();
          }
        ).getProgress();
      }
      function runProgram() {
        try {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
            function () {
              google.script.run.runProgram();
              getProgress();
            }
          ).startProgress();
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**References**

- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)